# Excel formula to show values if met in certain criteria. IF formula assitance

Tags: excel, wps

[image]

[image]

I am trying to show values under the dates on the first picture by taking information from the second picture. Im trying to make this work,
`=IF(C4<April!C4>C5,April!C4,"")`
Basically it should show the value from 2nd picture (April!C4) only if it is falling under the target category. Shown in picture 1.

Comment: Split this C4<April!C4>C5 into two tests within an AND() function, so and(April!C4>C4,April!C4<C5). Then make sure of what values are being tested.

Comment: Thank you @SolarMike, that's what was missing.